# SherlockActionBar gets locked on orientation change

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using sherloackActionBar and have made the menu always visible. Now when I am changing my device from portrait to landscape and then again to portrait, the menus get locked (not able to click on any options)
Now when I again change the orientation the previously menu click actions start working. This issue also looks very strange  to me as it happens only once (while we do it first time,then it works fine).

Can anyone please help me out if I need to add any attributes or something else. I am using   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" which seems to be the root cause for the problem according to me. Please correct me if am wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Jake Wharton himself in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460935/actionbar-tabs-overlapping-on-screen-rotation/17461084#17461084)

*ActionBarSherlock is a compatibility layer which exists inside the content view of an activity. This is a bit different than the native action bar which exists inside the window but outside of the normal content view.*

*Because of this fact, it cannot properly recreate itself when you declare in the manifest that you handle orientation changes. If you prevent ABS from recreating the action bar views there are almost always noticible artifacts like what you picture.*

*TL;DR: ActionBarSherlock does not work with configChanges="orientation"*

**BUT I've recently found myself in a lucky situation, which apparently solved this same problem.**

I'm not sure if this will fix it for sure, but **if you set a PADDING to the tabs in the styles of actionbar, the problem will be gone, and you will be able to click the tabs normally.

Heres the code I used, specifically for TabView style (I've used this [style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/))

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBarTab" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab</item>        
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Try it and let us all know if it worked for you. This might be a promising solution if you confirm it.